# Future Support of Magento 1.9 - Security issues

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, security

We are developing a B2B platform on Magento 1.x with a lot of custom-built modules. Upgrading on Magento 2 will be an enormous effort. Therefore we would like to develop on Magento 1.x longer than 3 years after Magento 2 is released.

Is it predictable if the security of Magento 1.x systems will be seriously affected when the support ends?